# asp.net web service with 2 return

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have a web service to fill html tags.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetHelloMessage(string country)
{
string test = "<div>amin</div>";
return test;
}
```

and jquery is:

```
    url: ServiceUrl,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    timeout: 15000,
    success: function (d) {
        if (d.length > 0) {
            var c = JSON.parse(d);
            if ($(".test1div").length) {
                $(".test1div").html(c.Content1)
            }if ($(".test2div").length) {
                $(".test2div").html(c.Content2)
            }
```

how to code web service to fill test2div tag ? how to add to return text from web service?
example:

```
string Content1 = "<div>amin</div>";
string Content2 = "<div>reza</div>;
string Content3 = Content1 + Content2;
return Content3;
```

please help me with more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy you can concatenate strings

like

```
string test = "<div id='test_tag'>amin</div>$<div id='test_tag'>amin2</div>";
return test;
```

then split this string in client script

```
 if ($(".testreturn").length) {
      $(".testreturn").html((data.d).split('$')[0])
 } 
 } if ($(".test2return").length) {
      $(".test2return").html((data.d).split('$')[1])
 }
```

**You were looking for two there is the solution for more use list as return and process like this did in below**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyWebService.asmx/SayAllTheHellos",
    data: "{ firstName: 'Aidy', lastName: 'F' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var myData = data.d;
        alert(myData.length + " hellos");
        for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++ ) {
            alert(myData[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please read again my question . i have edited and explain my request more.